# Electron: Manage the sound volume level of inner webviews

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, webview, electron

I am developing an application wherein a couple of `webview` elements hosting various **HTML** documents (some having node integration) which are reproducing different audio (mp3 and wav) files. I have been endeavouring for a couple of hours already to find a way in which I can set the volume of some of those `webview` tags to certain level. I am not a professional at **NodeJS** and ergo what I've tried is, I presume, more than simple, however, I failed getting anything to work.

**Conception A**: Select (*identify*) the webview via **JavaScript** and then run **JavaScript** code in it (currently attempting to do so via **IPC Renderer** (`.send()`) messages from root to webview) which is setting the volume for all video and audio elements within the hosted document.

Problem: If new elements of those are created they will have their native volume.

**Conception B**: Utilise some NodeJS library or resource to set (perhaps) something alike as "maximum volume" or "maximum window volume" (webviews have their own processes, as far as I am concerned).

**Edit:** Setting a master volume level for the entire Atom Shell Browser Window (not for each separate webview) would also work as a compromise version.

**Edit:** Chrome is able to this for its different tabs; each represented as a webview.

Any tip, resource, referrence or a library would be really appreciated!